# I just wrote 3 html code and stackoverflow went bug

Tags: html

```html
I think this code is as short as I can't explain

<form action="https://codepen.io/cavad/pen/MWJzLzJ">
<button>cavad</button>
<input type="text" id="yazi"></form>
```

Please find the code at codepen.io.

```
https://codepen.io/cavad/pen/MWJzLzJ
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain what you want help with

Comment: please enter the codepen link and click the button

Comment: You're setting the form action to the url of your codepen, so that's what shows up when you click the button

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="https://codepen.io/cavad/pen/MWJzLzJ">
    <button type="submit">cavad</button>
    <input type="text" id="yazi">
</form>

Try this by using this your problem will be solved, Whenever you use button you have to give this button type which is submit. And you don't add that in your code and that is why you are facing issues in your code.
```

Comment: Hi! Please consider adding some explanation so that future readers can understand how this code works